# Is it possible to publish a git repository or a zip file to CloudControl directly by REST API?

Tags: cloudcontrol

I want to publish a maven project to CloudControl by REST API, not by command line tool, is it possible? That means, create a app by REST API, deploy source or binary code by REST API. Just like Heroku, I can build a url directly into app using REST API https://api.heroku.com/apps/myapp/builds. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

We currently don't provide a way to upload images directly. You'd first have to push to the Git remote which will build the image. All other steps like creating an app/deployment, deploying or adding add-ons are available via the REST-API. You can see examples of the API usage in the [python library](https://github.com/cloudControl/pycclib) the command line client uses.

Comment: Thanks, if I push code to the Git remote by git command, then how to deploy using REST API? Is API /app/[app_name]/deployment/[dep_name]/worker/? What's the value of command parameter?